# Importing ES6 modules from multi-compiled UMD/CJS/ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, node-modules, umd

Using ES6 [boilerplate generator](https://github.com/duivvv/generator-module-boilerplate), I have built a moduleA that exports CommonJS (via Babel), UMD (via Rollup, unminified & minified version), and 
ES2015 via Babel. In other words, my module's `package.json` has

```
  "main": "cjs/index.js",
  "browser": "dist/moduleA.js",
  "module": "es/index.js",
  "jsxnext:main": "es/index.js",
```

Now I am building a moduleB that uses similar setup. What would be the best way to reference moduleA from moduleB? What would be the difference between `require("moduleA")` vs `import { X } from "moduleA"`. Basically I do not understand how different export options (main/browser/module) can be used from another module.  Thanks!

Comment: Those fields in the `package.json` are explicitly pointing to different builds for different environments. [Here's an explanation of the different fields meaning.](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec). From the coding PoV it should not change anything, but you probably should hint the bundler which build it should take. [Webpack offers you a configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) to tell in what order it should lookup the fields when resolving a module. The default is `browser`.

Comment: @MarcoL thanks, so each packaging system (webpack, rollup, ...) could use a different field from package.json?  And the choice is controlled by the settings, per each referenced module? In that case, if A uses B, and B uses C, who controls which setting is used from C when I build A? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Technically the fields in the `package.json` should be fixed and valid for all bundlers. Each specific bundler may have different default settings though and specific way to set an order of importance. The one for webpack is in the previous comment while for the others you need to findout.